# netfilter-persistent seems ok but does not load rules after reboot

Tags: networking, 20.04, iptables

Other people have similar issues but I tried all their approaches with missing iptable entries on boot, no success so far :| (it appears not to be a typo in the iptable files during load)

I've added a simple rule to iptables

`sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8140 -j ACCEPT`

and executed
`sudo service netfilter-persistent save`

I've checked that the 8140 rule is in the iptables rules with
`sudo cat /etc/iptables/rules.v4`

After rebooting however
`sudo iptables -L INPUT -v -n` does not show my 8140 INPUT entry.

`systemctl status netfilter-persistent`
says all ok

```
samuel@samuel-VirtualBox:~$ systemctl status netfilter-persistent
* netfilter-persistent.service - netfilter persistent configuration
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service.d
             `-iptables.conf
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-02-20 11:21:47 CET; 10min ago
       Docs: man:netfilter-persistent(8)
    Process: 642 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 642 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Feb 20 11:21:47 samuel-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
Feb 20 11:21:47 samuel-VirtualBox netfilter-persistent[649]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
Feb 20 11:21:47 samuel-VirtualBox netfilter-persistent[649]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Feb 20 11:21:47 samuel-VirtualBox systemd[1]: Finished netfilter persistent configuration.
```

So the service is enabled, when I manually run `sudo service netfilter-persistent reload` it seems to load the rules properly, because the 8140 INPUT chain is then shown.

Any hints on what to do would be welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar issue with the `netfilter-persistent`.

### Description

`netfilter-persistent` would normally start on boot, I confirmed this in syslog

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep netfilter | tail
Apr  6 11:40:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...
Apr  6 11:40:54 raspberrypi netfilter-persistent[381]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/15-ip4tables start
Apr  6 11:40:55 raspberrypi netfilter-persistent[381]: run-parts: executing /usr/share/netfilter-persistent/plugins.d/25-ip6tables start
Apr  6 11:40:55 raspberrypi netfilter-persistent[381]: Warning: skipping IPv6 (no rules to load)
Apr  6 11:40:55 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started netfilter persistent configuration.
```

But running `iptables -L` yielded no rules from `/etc/iptables/rules.v4`. Manually runnig `iptables-restore < /etc/iptables/rules.v4` or restarting the service as you did worked.

### Workaround

My workaround is to delay the start of the service after `network.target`. I opened the systemd unit file `/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=netfilter persistent configuration
DefaultDependencies=no
Wants=network-pre.target systemd-modules-load.service local-fs.target
Before=network-pre.target shutdown.target
After=systemd-modules-load.service local-fs.target network.target
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent start
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/netfilter-persistent stop

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and added `network.target` to the `After=` line. Now `netfilter-persistent` runs a bit later in the boot process and all the rules are present without me manually re-running it.

### EDIT: Found the issue

So, just after posting this, I did some more digging, and discovered that there is an init script which I created and forgot about. The script was in `/etc/network/if-up.d` running `iptables-restore` from a different location than `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` - that explains why moving the `netfilter-persistent` after `network.target` fixed the issue for me. I would suggest that you search your init scripts and look for any iptables-related stuff.

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to work.  I have the same behaviour as you and the one asking the questions.  I added this in /usr/lib/systemd/system/netfilter-persistent.service  

`After=systemd-modules-load.service local-fs.target network.target `

I did see a line like this in journalctl, not sure if this is related 

`Dec 28 11:30:09 domain.ca systemd[1]: netfilter-persistent.service: Job network.target/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with netfilter-persistent.service/start
Dec 28 11:30:13 domain.ca systemd[1]: Starting netfilter persistent configuration...`